# Анимирование наследников QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, c++

- Есть класс унаследованный от QGraphicsItem;
- На сцену мне нужно поместить 100 экземпляров этого класса;
- Как сделать так чтобы по таймеру они двигались?
- Есть идея через сигналы-слоты изменять их координты по истечению таймера.
- Есть ли более элегантное решение, нежели в цикле делать connect для каждого экземпляра?

Comment: Выбросить такую модель. У Вас должен быть класс, который умеет рисовать в окне, а также вектор, в котором будут храниться данные для 100 объектов. Когда нужно отрисовать, просто вызывается 

    foreach (obj, list) Drawer(obj);

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про устройстство графических движков и как организовать в них fps, я думаю это может подтолкнуть вас в нужном направлении.

Comment: Можешь подсказать годных материалов по теме?

Comment: @leff_tolstoi раньше видел хорошую статью, именно на тему fps, но не смог найти. Но для начала можешь ознакомиться с циклом статей http://habrahabr.ru/post/102930/